# gcc: strange behaviour with '-fno-strict-aliasing' when reading from hardware register

Tags: c, pointers, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

I am trying to debug a C program using gdb.The compile flags that I am using are as below

```
-fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DNO_OLD_ERF_TYPES -Werror  -Wredundant-decls -O2 -DNDEBUG -DBYTESWAP -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g
```

The version of the compiler that I am using is

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The disputed code is the following line

```
spm->num_streams = (uint16_t)((MkIV->stream_counts >> 16 ) & 0xfff);
```

Value of num_streams `with` `-fno-strict-aliasing`

```
 0xffff (4095)
```

Value of num_streams `WITHOUT-fno-strict-aliasing`

```
 0x1 (1)
```

Now it is worth noting the actual value of `mkIV->stream_counts` is `0x10020`.This is read from a `HARDWARE REGISTER`

the value we are interested in is `spm->num_streams` is `BIT27:BIT16`.Therefore the expected value is `'1'`

If I were to replace

```
spm->num_streams = (uint16_t)((MkIV->stream_counts >> 16 ) & 0xfff);
```

with

```
spm->num_streams = (uint16_t)((MkIV->stream_counts & 0xfff0000) >> 16);
```

then I get the value of `0x1(1)` with and without `-fno-strict-aliasing`

The stream_counts in MkIV structure (`MkIV->stream_counts` is of `uint32_t type`)

```
spm->num_streams is of type uint16_t
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: What type is `stream_counts`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - see added explanation in question

Comment: Is `stream_counts` qualified as `volatile`?

Comment: qualifying stream_counts as volatile fixes the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since qualifying `stream_counts` with `volatile` fixes the problem then it would seem that you were impacted by the *as-if* rule which basically says that if the compiler can modify the program as long as it can determine that it will not effect the *observable behavior*. cppreference [has a nice explanation here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) and although it is written with respect to *C++* most of it applies to *C* as well. The code examples are especially instructive.

Unlike the *draft C++ standard* the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) only explicitly refers to the *as-if* rule in the index which points to section `5.1.2.3` *Program execution* in paragraph *3* it says(*emphasis mine*):

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An
>   actual **implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
>   value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced** (including any caused by
>   calling a function or accessing a volatile object).

it does use the *as if* phrase in some of the examples, from paragraph *11* we have the following example:

```
float f1, f2;
double d;
/* ... */
f1 = f2 * d;
```

and the following text says(*emphasis mine*):

> the multiplication may be executed using single-precision arithmetic if the implementation can ascertain that the result would be the same **as if** it were executed using double-precision arithmetic

and if we look at section `6.7.3` *Type qualifiers* paragraph *6* says(*emphasis mine*):

> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
>   implementation or have other unknown side effects. **Therefore any expression referring
>   to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine**, as described in 5.1.2.3. Furthermore, at every sequence point the value last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown factors mentioned previously.116)[...]

which puts restrictions on the short cuts a compiler can take with respect to `volatile` qualified objects. Section `5.1.2.3` paragraph *5* covers the *The least requirements on a conforming implementation are*.

Answer (score 2):

You are a victim of the 'as-if' rule. The compiler has no idea you're reading from a hardware register. When you write:

```
spm->num_streams = (uint16_t)((MkIV->stream_counts & 0xfff0000) >> 16);
```

The compiler has every right to do this:

```
uint16_t j = MkIV->stream_counts;
MkIV->stream_counts &= 0xfff0000;
MkIV->stream_counts >>= 16;
sp->num_streams = MKIV->stream_counts;
MkIV->stream_counts = j;
```

Most likely, you can work around the problem by making `stream_counts` volatile or "laundering" the read through a volatile pointer.

Instead of `MkIV->stream_counts`, use `*(volatile uint16_t *)&MkIV->stream_counts`.

Comment: in your explanation are you saying 'uint16_t j' is a temporary variable used by the compiler?

Comment: can you explain you answer in a bit more detail.

Comment: @liv2hak Yes, it's a temporary. I'm not sure what you want more detail on.